# How can I ask user to open their bluetooth? using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm trying to make  web app where where I need to ask user to open their bluetooth after the web app is loaded. using a pop up message where in if the user click ok, user's bluetooth will automatically on else the web app will be close. using javascipt.
thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. What do you mean by "close"? And by open bluetooth, do you mean the computer's bluetooth settings?

Comment: Bluetooth Web API exists, but is supported only by Chrome on Android, so no iOS support at the moment. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API so you'd have to use something like Cordova or PhoneGap with a bluetooth-plugin

Comment: After the website is loaded, there will be pop up message asking user to open their Bluetooth, once clicking the "ok"  I'm just wondering if it is possible to open user's Bluetooth after clicking the button "ok". And for the close, if the user did not allow the website or cancel the confirm message, is it possible to automatically close the website?

Answer (score 0):

You can open options with ms-settings.

I don't know if it work for Mac but it work for Windows

`<a href="ms-settings:bluetooth">Activate buletooth</a>`